# Link Google Sheet cells to Google Map polygon attributes

Tags: google-sheets, google-maps

I have a Google Spreadsheet with values for things like property addresses and contact details. I have a custom Google Map with polygons that match up with the spreadsheet data.

Would it be at all possible to link (automatically or manually) the value of a cell in the spreadsheet to display in the polygon attributes?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what your custom map and data looks like? In lieu of that, is this guide any help? -- [Google Maps Data layer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer).